# how can I add seconds to a particular date to get Exact date value in python?

Tags: python, datetime

how can i add seconds to particular datetime in python.
I have a txt file

```
Time [ms]

3577382125627.000   
3577382137616.000

3577382137618.000
```

those values are in milliseconds and i want to add them to date 1-1-1904 to get date values.
?

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
a = datetime.datetime(1904,1,1)
print(a)
s = str(data[1]['Time [ms]'])

y = s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')

z =  timedelta (seconds = y)    + a

print(y)
```

Comment: you add the timedelta to the datetime. Edits make it look like you might be doing that already, but you are passing the ms to the seconds? Maybe divide by 1000.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: data[1] is undefined, and did you want to print z?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the value to the `milliseconds` argument of [the `timedelta` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1904, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=3577382125627)
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 21, 15, 25, 627000)
```

Comment: Also, `y = s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` is a rather convoluted method of extracting an integer value from a string - `y = int(float(s))` is much cleaner.